# Reducing the result of $z=e^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2xy)$ after a coordinate rotation by $45^\circ$

Tags: reduced-residue-system

Starting with 
$$z=e^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2xy)$$
I must make the substitution
$$\begin{align}
x &\to \phantom{-} x\cos 45^\circ + y\sin 45^\circ \\
y &\to -x\sin 45^\circ + y \cos 45^\circ \end{align}$$
where 
$$\cos 45^\circ = \sin 45^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

I tried reducing, but I am making a mistake. Please help me find it. I got

$$\begin{align}
z&=e^{2}\cdot\cos(2\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot 0) \\
z&=e^{2}
\end{align}$$

Wolfram alpha will graph the function without reducing it:

[image]

Comment: What is the original problem?

Comment: reduce what exactly?

Comment: @The Integrator reduce the sin and cos to the simplest possible equation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but it looks like you are rotating the coordinate system.

let:
$x = \frac{\sqrt {2}}{2} u + \frac{\sqrt {2}}{2} v\\
y = \frac{\sqrt {2}}{2} u - \frac{\sqrt {2}}{2} v$

$x^2 - y^2 = 2uv\\
2xy = u^2 - v^2$

$z = e^{2uv}\cos (u^2 - v^2)$

Comment: I would like to understand this method better please make reference to the name of this method.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2-y^2\pm 2ixy=(x\pm iy)^2$  Therefore $e^{(x^2-y^2)}cos(2xy)=\frac{e^{(x+iy)^2}+e^{(x-iy)^2}}{2}$.

I presume this is what the question is seeking.